# OpenGL - glUniformBlockBinding after or before glLinkProgram?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to use Uniform Buffer Objects to share my projection matrix accross different shaders (e.g., Deferred pass for solid objects and Forward pass for transparent ones). I think that I'll add more data to the UBO later on, when the complexity grows up. My problem is that the Red Book says:

> To explicitly control a uniform block's binding, call **glUniformBlockBinding()** before calling **glLinkProgram()**.

But the [online documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glUniformBlockBinding.xhtml) says:

> When a program object is linked or re-linked, the uniform buffer object binding point assigned to each of its active uniform blocks is reset to zero.

What am I missing? Should I bind the Uniform Block after or before the linking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glUniformBlockBinding​` needs the program name and the index where to find the block in this particular program.

```
 void glUniformBlockBinding​( GLuint program​, GLuint uniformBlockIndex​, GLuint uniformBlockBinding​ );
```

`uniformBlockIndex​` can be obtained by calling `glGetUniformBlockIndex` on the program.

```
 GLuint glGetUniformBlockIndex​( GLuint program​, const char *uniformBlockName​ );
```

From the API (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetUniformBlockIndex):

> program​ must be the name of a program object for which the command glLinkProgram​ must have been called in the past, although it is not required that glLinkProgram​ must have succeeded. The link could have failed because the number of active uniforms exceeded the limit.

So the correct order is:

```
void glLinkProgram(GLuint program​);
GLuint glGetUniformBlockIndex​( GLuint program​, const char *uniformBlockName​ );
void glUniformBlockBinding​( GLuint program​, GLuint uniformBlockIndex​, GLuint uniformBlockBinding​ );
```

Comment: So let's say that I want to create a unique UBO and use it in several shaders. I should retrieve each block index with `glGetUniformBlockIndex`, then populate it with `glBufferData` using the layout of any of them (it should be the same if I mark it as `shared`), associate it to a common binding point using `glUniformBlockBinding`, and finally call `glBindBufferBase` for each block index so they all point to the same binding point. Is that correct?

Comment: Almost. `glBindbufferBase` maps a binding point to a `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER`, so you don't need that for every blockIndex. See here the example: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/3490-2/